# how to add the same content in all twig templates in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-2.1

I have a vertical menu in the main template in my website where I put the same content in all the website pages and all the other templates extends the main template. My question is; How can we display the same content in my menu in all pages without passing the same objects in all other controllers that display a webpage extending the main one, for example:

I have a vertical menu in my main layout.html.twig where I display 3 objects: object1, object2 and object3.

When calling render function in my controllers do I have to always pass object1, object2 and object3 to templates that extends the main template?

Isn't there a more easy and elegant way?

Comment: sorry but it's not the same question, i already checked the link given by Dmitry Krasun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to separate this menu from layout. Make an action in controller for this menu, action will manage displaying your menu and objects in this menu. Then render this action in layout template.

```
{% render "AcmeMenuBundle:Front:showMenu" %}
```

Comment: I think it will not be effective to make sub-request just for rendering menu (on every page).

Answer (score 0):

If your question is about building menus then I think the most elegant way is to use KnpMenuBundle - https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenuBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md.

But if your question is about add content to all twig templates then I saw the same answer -  [Fetch data from inside a twig template in Symfony2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512180/fetch-data-from-inside-a-twig-template-in-symfony2).